# Django celery task using selenium. WebDriverException()

Tags: django, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, celery-task

I use selenium to login instagram account and getting follower information. In the homepage i have form for adding new instagram account. When i add new account, view of that page return follower and following informations of that account.
I also have a celery task for updating a follower count of every instagram account in the database. And i use almost same codes in the tasks.py file. But when celery task is working error happen.  Everything work perfectly in view.  Application running in docker containers

```
ERROR

instagram-celery-beat-1  | [2023-04-16 16:52:17,964: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task update_instagram_stats (users.tasks.update_instagram_stats)
instagram-rabbitmq-1     | 2023-04-16 16:52:17.964 [info] <0.1127.0> connection <0.1127.0> (172.27.0.4:56174 -> 172.27.0.2:5672): user 'rabbitmq' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
instagram-celery-1       | [2023-04-16 16:52:17,994: INFO/MainProcess] Task users.tasks.update_instagram_stats[ba9ece0d-18d9-44f4-96ff-32cde8f6d1b0] received
instagram-rabbitmq-1     | 2023-04-16 16:52:18.005 [info] <0.1143.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.1143.0> (172.27.0.3:54132 -> 172.27.0.2:5672)
instagram-rabbitmq-1     | 2023-04-16 16:52:18.010 [info] <0.1143.0> connection <0.1143.0> (172.27.0.3:54132 -> 172.27.0.2:5672): user 'rabbitmq' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
instagram-celery-1       | [2023-04-16 16:52:18,014: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] 00000000000000000000000000
instagram-celery-1       | [2023-04-16 16:52:19,832: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
instagram-celery-1       | [2023-04-16 16:52:22,288: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task users.tasks.update_instagram_stats[ba9ece0d-18d9-44f4-96ff-32cde8f6d1b0] raised unexpected: WebDriverException()
instagram-celery-1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
instagram-celery-1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 451, in trace_task
instagram-celery-1       |     R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
instagram-celery-1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 734, in __protected_call__
instagram-celery-1       |     return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
instagram-celery-1       |   File "/code/users/tasks.py", line 62, in update_instagram_stats
instagram-celery-1       |     driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver',options=option)
instagram-celery-1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
instagram-celery-1       |     super().__init__(
instagram-celery-1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 104, in __init__
instagram-celery-1       |     super().__init__(
instagram-celery-1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
instagram-celery-1       |     self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
instagram-celery-1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
instagram-celery-1       | #6 0x5596363dc693 <unknown>
instagram-celery-1       | #7 0x5596363af03a <unknown>
instagram-celery-1       | #8 0x5596363b017e <unknown>
instagram-celery-1       | #9 0x559636601dbd <unknown>
instagram-celery-1       | #10 0x559636605c6c <unknown>
instagram-celery-1       | #11 0x55963660f4b0 <unknown>
instagram-celery-1       | #12 0x559636606d63 <unknown>
instagram-celery-1       | #13 0x5596365d9c35 <unknown>instagram-celery-1       | #14 0x55963662a138 <unknown>
instagram-celery-1       | #15 0x55963662a2c7 <unknown>
instagram-celery-1       | #16 0x559636638093 <unknown>
instagram-celery-1       | #17 0x7fe0bd4aaea7 start_thread
instagram-celery-1       |
```

```
tasks.py

@shared_task
def update_instagram_stats():
    # retrieve all Instagram objects
    instagrams = Instagram.objects.all()
    print("00000000000000000000000000")

    # iterate through Instagram objects and update stats
    for instagram in instagrams:
        # log in to the account using Selenium
        url = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/"
        option = Options()
        option.headless = True
        print("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver',options=option)
        print("11111111111111111111111")
        try:
            driver.get(url)
            time.sleep(2)
            username = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'username')))
            username.send_keys(instagram.username)
            time.sleep(2)
            password = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'password')))
            password.send_keys(instagram.password)
            time.sleep(3)
            loginbutton = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]/button')))
            loginbutton.click()
            time.sleep(20)

            driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/' + instagram.username)
            time.sleep(10)
            follower_count = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[href="/' + instagram.username + '/followers/"] span').get_attribute('title')
            following_count= driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[href="/' + instagram.username + '/following/"] span').text

            print(follower_count)
            print(following_count)

            # update the Instagram object with the new counts and save it to the database
            instagram.followers = int(follower_count.replace(',', ''))
            instagram.following = int(following_count.replace(',', ''))
            instagram.save()

            print("Done==============================>")
        finally:
            # close the Selenium browser window
            driver.quit()
```

```
views.py

@login_required
def account_list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InstagramForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            instagram = form.save(commit=False)
            instagram.user = request.user

            # log in to the account using Selenium
            url = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/" 
            option = Options() #newly added 
            option.headless = True #newly added
            option.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
            option.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver',options=option)
            driver.get(url)
            username = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'username')))
            username.send_keys(instagram.username)
            time.sleep(2)
            password = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'password')))
            password.send_keys(instagram.password)
            time.sleep(3)
            loginbutton = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]/button')))
            loginbutton.click()
            time.sleep(10)
            driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/' + instagram.username)
            time.sleep(5)
            follower_count = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[href="/' + instagram.username + '/followers/"] span').get_attribute('title')
            following_count= driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[href="/' + instagram.username + '/following/"] span').text

            # update the Instagram object with the new counts and save it to the database
            instagram.followers = int(follower_count.replace(',', ''))
            instagram.following = int(following_count.replace(',', ''))
            instagram.save()

            # close the Selenium browser window
            driver.quit()
            return redirect('home_page')
    else:
        form = InstagramForm()
    instagrams = Instagram.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'users/homepage.html', {'form': form, 'instagrams': instagrams})
```

I try to change that line like this:driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=option)